# Fuzzy lookup transformation in SSIS

Tags: ssis

HI now i have id with me but in other table
so now i did inner join for matching both security id and taking out companyid...

description..

TABLE identifier

```
keyid    securityid        id     identifier
48712205    5033048    158976       001546AL4
```

TABLE UPDATENAV

```
Date    SecurityId    SecurityType    EntryPrice    Mark    CompanyName
2011-08-31 00:00:00.000    5033048    Bond    1.057500    NULL    AK Steel Corporation
2011-08-31 00:00:00.000    5049118    Bond    1.091250    NULL    Aspect Software, Inc.
```

NOW I HAVE DONE INNER JOIN TO GET identifier

```
 ALTER VIEW TempView AS
 select UpdateNAV.SecurityId ,identifier , Mark
 FROM [mydata].[dbo].[UpdateNAV] inner join dbo.Identifier
 on UpdateNAV.SecurityId = Identifier.SecurityId
```

now i have used fuzzy lookup to match this.. but problem is

in fuzzy lookup column

right side is having columns from flatfile and left side is having only two columns from MY TEMP VIEW...

now i'm matching company id from flatfile and temp view... in look up but what about price how can i insert
it how do i mapping ?? it is not present inright side as it is not present into MY View

what should i have to use

[image]

after this i took OLEDB DESTINATION FOR FURTHER MAPPING LIKE BELOW...
IS THERE ANY NEED TO WRITE UPDATE QUERY ? OR MAPPING WILL DO WORK?
[image]

Comment: IS THERE ANY ONE WHO TELLS ME WHERE I GO WRONG

Comment: can you clarify your requirement?  are you trying to insert or update a pricing row whenever the identifier matches the asset identifier?